# What are some other ways of saying "I don't believe you"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

What are some other ways of saying "I don't believe you"? I have been able to think of a few answers, but most of them contain the verb "believe", but can you think of one without it? All I could think of was: bullshit, nonsense and other words like that, but I can't think of any idiom or phrase without the verb "believe". Is there any good idiom or phrase you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

> I'm [**not buying it**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+buy).
>
> You're [**full of it**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/full+of+it).
>
> You're a **liar**.
>
> You're trying to [**pull one over on**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+one+over+on) me.
>
> You're **[pulling my leg](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pulling+my+leg)**.

All of them mean you don't believe the other person, though the last is mostly lighthearted.